# How to select rows where one column value is the same on separate dates without using variables?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a DB Fiddle as an example: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vX7yFVk8j6FPTSm2QVoPNE/2

I'm trying to figure out how to find all bookings for a guest who has booked one room several times on different dates. I can't use a static value/variable like `bookings.check_in_date = '2018-03-05'`, `bookings.guest_id = 001` or use subqueries.

I tried:

```
SELECT bookings.guest_id, bookings.room_number, bookings.check_in_date, bookings.check_out_date
FROM bookings
GROUP BY bookings.guest_id, bookings.room_number, bookings.check_in_date, bookings.check_out_date
HAVING count(distinct bookings.check_in_date) >= 2;
```

However, it isn't giving me the result I'm looking for but rather I'm looking for this as a result:

```
guest_id, room_number, check_in_date, check_out_date
1, 203, 2018-03-01T00:00:00.000Z, 2018-03-07T00:00:00.000Z
1, 203, 2018-03-14T00:00:00.000Z, 2018-03-21T00:00:00.000Z
```

**Schema (PostgreSQL v10.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE guests (
  id integer,
  name text,
  address text,
  city text,
  state text,
  postal_code integer,
  phone_number numeric(10)
);

CREATE TABLE rooms (
  room_number integer,
  floor_number integer,
  view boolean,
  bed_type text
);

CREATE TABLE bookings (
  id integer,
  guest_id integer,
  room_number integer,
  order_date date,
  check_in_date date,
  check_out_date date
);

INSERT INTO guests (id, name, address, city, state, postal_code, phone_number)
VALUES
(1, 'John', '5 8th Avenue', 'New York', 'New York', 10001, 2021110190),
(2, 'Jane', '13 Wall St', 'New York', 'New York', 10001, 1112020190),
(3, 'Jim', '12 Water St', 'New York', 'New York', 10001, 3332224444),
(4, 'Fang', '12 Broadway', 'New York', 'New York', 10001, 1234567890),
(5, 'Bruce', '123 1st Ave', 'New York', 'New York', 10001, 9871112222);

INSERT INTO rooms (room_number, floor_number, view, bed_type)
VALUES
(101, 1, FALSE, 'King'),
(102, 1, FALSE, 'Queens'),
(203, 2, FALSE, 'Queens'),
(204, 2, TRUE, 'King'),
(409, 4, TRUE, 'King');

INSERT INTO bookings (id, guest_id, room_number, order_date, check_in_date, check_out_date)
VALUES
(18001, 001, 203, '2018-03-05', '2018-03-01', '2018-03-07'),
(18002, 001, 203, '2018-03-05', '2018-03-14', '2018-03-21'),
(18003, 001, 409, '2018-03-05', '2018-11-27', '2018-11-30'),
(18004, 001, 204, '2018-03-05', '2018-11-27', '2018-11-30'),

(18007, 002, 409, '2018-05-05', '2018-05-05', '2018-05-12'),
(18002, 002, 203, '2018-03-05', '2018-03-14', '2018-03-21'),
(18006, 002, 409, '2018-06-05', '2018-07-04', '2018-07-07'),

(18005, 003, 409, '2018-06-05', '2018-08-05', '2018-08-12'),

(18008, 004, 409, '2018-09-05', '2018-09-05', '2018-09-12');
```

Comment: Why aren't you allowed to use sub-queries?

Comment: My school want us to learn how to do queries without them. I honestly prefer them because they're more readable to me.

Comment: What does it mean "booked one room on separate dates"?  Is that "booked the *same* room", "booked a room for one person", or just "booked one room and not two"?

Comment: It means, I have hotel room #1 booked from today through tomorrow. I also have hotel room #1 booked next week through next week +1 day.

Comment: Why does your fiddle use MySQL but you tag Postgres here?

Comment: Sorry, I just fixed that and updated the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just counting the number of bookings per guest_id should get your the guests who have more than one booking

```
select a.*
from bookings a
join (
       select guest_id,room_number,count(*)
         from bookings
      group by guest_id,room_number
        having count(*)>1
      )b
  on a.guest_id=b.guest_id
And a.room_ number=b.room_number
```

Comment: Yes, but that uses a subquery and returns guests that have a single booking.

Comment: If using Postgres, this derived table subquery can become a CTE.

Comment: Single booking? count(*)>1

Comment: I had to look up CTE, we haven't been introduced to that. How do you go about doing that approach?

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph I guess I don't understand your query. However, it's not returning the result of:
    `guest_id, room_number, check_in_date, check_out_date`
    `1, 203, 2018-03-01T00:00:00.000Z, 2018-03-07T00:00:00.000Z`
    `1, 203, 2018-03-14T00:00:00.000Z, 2018-03-21T00:00:00.000Z`

Comment: Edited it to be guest who books the same room again